# Help beginner understand threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array of MyThreads (seen below) running, but they produce incorrect results. What is the problem here?

```
import java.util.*;
class MyThread extends Thread {
  public static long N;
  public static long sum = 0;
  synchronized public void inc() {
    sum++;
  }
  public void run() {
    for (long i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      inc();
    }
  }
  public MyThread(long num) {
    N = num;
  }
}
```

My guess is that the threads are interrupting each other, causing the incorrect results, but I don't understand where or how.

Comment: How are you running these threads, and what results do you expect?

Comment: What are the incorrect results? What are you expecting as results? How about the code snippet where you are starting and checking them?

Comment: You're incrementing a static variable.  What do you expect to happen with a variable that's shared by all instances of MyThread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it appears that `N` is a per-thread iteration count, so it shouldn't be static.

Second, since `sum` is a static member, your `inc` method should also be static, otherwise you won't be synchronizing on the static fields of the class.

Comment: Nevermind. I have figured this out on my own. It was a poorly written question.